# Angular Js SPA is not working after publishing in IIS 8.5

Tags: angularjs, iis-8.5

I'm using SPA technique using AngularJS in ASP.NET MVC framework,AngularJS routing between pages are working fine when it's run from VS2013,but after hosting the application in to IIS8.5 routing not working.

When i run the app using IIS express the url was http://localhost:12345/#/home
After publishing [http://localhost/myapp/#/home](http://localhost/vgtmonetst/#/home)

Here is my app.js,

```
 $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        controller: "homeController",
        templateUrl: "/app/views/home.html"
    });
```

In `index.html`

```
<li> <a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
```

When i publish my app in windows azure, app is working fine. Because the url was `myapp.azurewebsite.net`. `myapp.azurewebsite.net/#/home`

How can i host similarly in local IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost find find the answer -- that is all about absolute file path.

Quick fix:

Change `templateUrl: "/app/views/home.html"` to `templateUrl: "app/views/home.html"` (remove the heading slash)

Answer:

If you specify the `templateUrl` as `/app/views/home.html`, which starts with `/`, you tell the browser to get it from root.

If your webapp is stored in `http://localhost/myapp/`, your browser will visit `http://localhost/app/views/home.html` to get the template.

That also explains why your app works fine when it is places in root directory, but not working in sub directories, like `http://localhost/myapp/#/home` .

Do not worry about the side effect of relative path. All the resources are calculated relative to `index.html`.

Comment: Superb. After removing / working fine :). Also for images..some of them it is working. for images i've used lazy loading feature... bn-lazy-src [http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2498-lazy-loading-image-with-angularjs.htm]. for this img type... again the same problem. Always showing default image.. even though image exists. Can you suggest.. Edit my question. added image.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi These images are stored outside the angular's directory? If so, the image path is irrelevant to the angular path, and they're uploaded to some backend? you may use absolute path for these files. and store images' base path using angular's `constant` to specify the backend's image storage directory.